# What is a good location for a server-like application to save its permanent data?

Tags: server, filesystem, directory, services, directory-structure

I have an application that needs to save some session information etc permanent data. What would be a good system directory for this?

Something under `var/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what kind of data you're planning to store.

Read-only (Machine independent)-> /usr/share/"your_app"

Read-only (Machine specific) -> /usr/lib/"your_app"

Read-Write -> /var/lib/"your_app"

Please visit [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) for more detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

- mysql uses /var/lib/mysql so yes, /var/{lib/}{your_directory}/ is an option.
- `/srv` is a location used for group files. [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM):

> **/srv : Data for services provided by this system**
>
> Rationale
>
> This main purpose of specifying this is so that users may find the location of the data files for particular service, and so that services which require a single tree for readonly data, writable data and scripts (such as cgi scripts) can be reasonably placed. Data that is only of interest to a specific user should go in that users' home directory.
>
> The methodology used to name subdirectories of /srv is unspecified as there is currently no consensus on how this should be done. One method for structuring data under /srv is by protocol, eg. ftp, rsync, www, and cvs. On large systems it can be useful to structure /srv by administrative context, such as /srv/physics/www, /srv/compsci/cvs, etc. This setup will differ from host to host. Therefore, no program should rely on a specific subdirectory structure of /srv existing or data necessarily being stored in /srv. However /srv should always exist on FHS compliant systems and should be used as the default location for such data.

I personally would use a personal mount point for this. Makes an easier life backing up this data.